# extract lines containing patterns file and save them in different files grep, sed, awk, print

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have this file

```
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10000024
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10000024
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
```

and these patterns

```
COL 1           

tom_fa_10005086
tom_fa_10013928
tom_fa_10000024
tom_fa_10011338
tom_fa_10003474
```

I want extract the lines when the pattern match with lines and keep it in a file.

But I have 150 patterns and I need that every match is saved it in a different files?
so I have I have 150 patterns, I would have 150 outputs files.

The results would look like:

File 1

```
   -   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10005086
    -   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
    -   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
    -   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
    -   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
    -   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
    -   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
```

File 2

```
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
```

file 3
......

I was thinking about:

grep -f file 1 file 1 | ....

grep -E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `patterns` file:

```
$ cat patterns
tom_fa_10005086
tom_fa_10013928
tom_fa_10000024
tom_fa_10011338
tom_fa_10003474
```

Then

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=NR; next} $NF in a {print > "outfile" a[$NF]}' patterns file
```

results in the following files:

```
$ head outfile?
==> outfile1 <==
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086

==> outfile2 <==
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928

==> outfile3 <==
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10000024
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10000024
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your first, large file is named `target.txt` and your second smaller file is named `source.txt`.

```
tail +3 source.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do grep "$line" target.txt > "$line"; done
```

### Explanation

- `tail +3 source.txt`: remove the first two lines of `source.txt`
- `| while IFS= read -r line; do <FOO>; done`: pipe this truncated file into the `while read` construct. This will iterate over each line of the truncated `source.txt`, doing `<FOO>` for each line.
- `grep "$line" target.txt > "$line"`: for each `source.txt` line, grep for it in `target.txt`, then write to a file named the same as the original string that you searched for.

A minor comment: if `source.txt` actually contains fixed strings instead of patterns, you can use the `-F` option for `grep`.

Comment: thanks, this ones was so helpful, It works perfectly, but I removed "results/"

Comment: @JulianaBC I edited to remove the subdirectory part. I notice that you are new here (welcome!). FWIW on StackExchange sites, you can say "thank you" by upvoting answers (clicking the up arrow on the left of answers). Cheers!